# read last row's only 1 column detail from a table in visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

i want to read the last entered customer id from customer table in visual studio!
how to read that VALUE?
(IN-BUILT SQL SERVER in visual studio )

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT TOP 1  id FROM CUSTOMER ORDER BY uniquecolumn DESC
```

Comment: i tried 
'dim k as string
k = "SELECT TOP 1  cid FROM clienttable ORDER BY uniquecolumn DESC"
'

But k's value is being shown as this statement!
i am sure that i have written it in a wrong way!

Comment: i even tried  
-`Imports System.Data.SqlClient`  
-**Public class**  
-
-`Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ahla\Documents\............;User Instance=True")
-Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
-Dim cdr As SqlDataReader`/br    -**form_load**  
-`cmd.Connection = cn`    
-**button_click**  
-`cn.Open()  
-cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 id FROM customer ORDER BY uniquecolumn DESC"  
-k= k=k + 1  
-id = k   
-cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  
-cn.Close()`

Comment: I am really sorry i do not know how to display or read the value. i am really new to this topic. i have learned MySQL where you type select .... from.... and the result appears in the next line but i do not know how to use in Visual Studio!! :(

Comment: Please set the unique column (ex:'id' ) in query ("SELECT TOP 1 id FROM customer ORDER BY id DESC")

Answer (score 0):

If you have an identity column you can use [IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175098.aspx):

> **IDENT_CURRENT**: "Returns the last identity value generated for a specified table or view. The last identity value generated can be for any session and any scope."

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
WHERE ID = IDENT_CURRENT('CUSTOMER_TABLE')
```

or if you don't have an identity column:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE)
```